# R plotly change label size

Tags: r, fonts, label, size, plotly

I made a heatmap with plotly, and have 300 variables on Y axis with long names, and all I want to do is to make them more readable. I managed to change the margin, so that y labels have more space, but they are too big.

How to change y labels font size? I've tried size parameter in yaxis, but it is just ignored.

```
p <- plot_ly(
    x = missing_data$bucket,
    y = missing_data$key,
    z = missing_data$count,
    type = "heatmap") %>%
    layout(
        xaxis = list(type = "category", tickangle = 0, tick0 = 10, dtick = 10),
        yaxis = list(type = "category", size = 3, tickwidth = 0, ticklen = 0.1, size = 15),
        margin = list(l = 150, r = 50, b = 50, t = 50, pad = 4))
p
```

Comment: You have `size` twice in `yaxis`. Try `yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 8))`. https://plot.ly/r/axes/

Comment: Thanks, you answered the question, it works!
P.S. the duplicate parameter of `size` was there by accident, because I've tried this many times.